# Recover postgres user in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, superuser

I need to recover the superuser privilege for the `postgres` user, because it lost the superuser qualification.

I cannot do anything in the `psql` shell, it gives the message

```
must be superuser to create superusers
```

The system is Ubuntu 16.04 and PostgreSQL 9.5.
Can I recover this `postgres` user?

Answer (score 3):

If you managed to remove superuser privileges from all your users, you'll have to start the database in single user mode:

1. Stop the database server as operating system user `postgres`:

   ```bash
   /path/to/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl stop -D /path/to/data/directory
   ```
2. Start the server in single user mode:

   ```bash
   /path/to/postgresql/bin/postgres --single -D /path/to/data/directory postgres
   ```

   Now you are a superuser.
3. Restore the superuser privilege:

   ```
   ALTER ROLE postgres SUPERUSER
   ```
4. Exit from the session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> if you are on Windows).
5. Restart PostgreSQL the way you normally do it.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe

Comment: @FernandoMiranda if that answer solved your problem, then please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that your question is marked as resolved