# Postgres login problems

Tags: postgresql

I used this statement to change the postgres role permissions:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH NOLOGIN.
```

I have only one role: the postgres default role.
Sorry for my stupidity. Now I can't login anyway to the DB.
If I try to connect to the DB tha answer is:

```
C:\>psql -h 192.168.167.31 -U postgres
Inserisci la password per l'utente postgres:
psql: FATALE:  al ruolo "postgres" non è consentito effettuare il login
```

Comment: That's easy, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51979863/6464308).

Comment: If you upvote the answer there, I could mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry i have a little more problem , on my pc i can't execute runas; it always says me the tha password or the username is incorrect;

Comment: I don't know enough about Windows for that. Why do you need `runas`?

Comment: I need runas to get postgres user from OS

Comment: Login as a local Administrator and try without `runas`.

Comment: https://fluca1978.github.io/2019/06/27/PostgreSQLSingleMode.html